# Can you overload what the object variable name itself returns?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Assume that I have a class called `MyClass`, and then I created an object from this class:

```
MyClass obj1;
```

What I want to do is to make `obj1` when used by itself to return something, for example assume that I want it to return an `int`, so if I did the following:

```
printf("%d", obj1);
```

Then `printf()` should print an `int`.

Can this be done in C++?

Comment: Not with `printf`. It is far too "stupid." It doesn't really know what it's receiving, so there's no way to infer what `obj1` needs to be converted into. This would be trivial with a `<<`  overload.

Comment: What does that `int` represent? There's several ways to do something similar to what you want, but which one to use depends on what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't just want to output `obj1`, but I also want to be able to pass it to any function, for example: `someFunction(obj1);  // I expect an int to be passed as argument`.

Comment: @Nikos C the `int` can be anything, for example it can be a member variable of `MyClass`, or it can be just a literal, etc.

Comment: If you use it where the compiler knows it  needs an `int` (or anything else) you want to make a [cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). I'm not a big fan of doing this. For readability you are typically better off writing a getter. The time saved on less typing can be easily eaten up by a single confused coworker trying to understand what's happening.

Comment: I meant what it represents, not the technical details of how its stored. Does the int represent the value of obj1? Or does it represent the serialized text form of obj1 for printing? Or does it represent just a property of obj1?

Comment: @Nikos C I just want to know if it is technically possible to make `obj1` by itself return an `int`, so it doesn't matter to me what this `int` represents at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do most of time (but `printf` would require a bit more effort):

```cpp
class MyObject {
...
    operator int() const { // user-defined conversion operator
        return /*the value you want to see*/;
    }
...
```

This way, at any time you pass the object to a function that accepts `int` and not `MyObject`, the conversion operator is called to get that int. It will also be called for explicit casts like `(int)obj`.

`printf` is problematic as it doesn’t accept specifically `int`—it accepts *anything* (the signature is, more or less, `int printf(const char *, ...)`). So you will have to call it like `printf("%d\n", (int)obj1);`.

I’d suggest not to use `printf` too much, it’s a C legacy so can’t be type-safe (e.g. `printf("%s", 1)` is an unevitable crash). Use [fmt](https://fmt.dev/) or iostreams, for example.